# Changing FireFox Push Message Provider

Tags: firefox, web-applications, push-notification

I would like to change my FireFox Push Message provider from the default wss://push.services.mozilla.com/ to whatever URL is required for Google Cloud Messaging. (Or possibly Windows Notification Service, whichever is “better”)

Is it sufficient to update the dom.push.serverURL parameter in about:config and, if so, what are the corresponding URLs that are required?

Also, can this be done programmatically via javascript for individual pages/web-apps?

Cheers Richard Maher

Comment: This new [FireCast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) feature is **extremely** exciting! Thank-you Google for listening and bypassing the usual speed-bumps on the road to progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The push provider needs to adhere to the Web Push protocol, so currently you can only use the Mozilla one and maybe the experimental Google one.

Obviously, you won't be able to use features that aren't in the Web Push standard.

It can't be done programmatically by non-privileged JavaScript, you could do it in an addon.

Comment: I assume competition regulators will require this setting to become much more like selecting a search-engine provider in the near future. Now that the Web Push standard no longer has to be dumbed-down to meet the inadequacies of Mozilla's autopush infrastructure, can Web-App authors not be allowed to access the same Push functionality of native apps?

Comment: What are you talking about? Selecting the web push provider and a search engine are two completely different things. There's no competition problem here, Mozilla doesn't care if Chrome users use GCM and Google doesn't care if Firefox users use Autopush.

Comment: The web push standard is unrelated to autopush. Autopush is an implementation of the standard, the standard is created independently.

Comment: I will be very surprised if an EU court doesn't decree it anti-competitive and an abuse of market position for a Browser manufacturer to mandate and restrict the user's choice of Push Service Provider to its own offering. Perhaps you were of the opinion that Microsoft was quite within its rights all those years ago to mandate Internet Explorer on Windows?  Some push services are free or cheaper, others have better analytics or performance and most do not have the luxury of a captive market in the browser that they also happen to produce. Close up Autopush and fix the specification!

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry.

Comment: While you're making your mind up you couldn't possibly give me the URL for the "experimental Google one" could ya?

Comment: It could be https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send, but I'm not sure. See https://github.com/marco-c/web-push/pull/70#issuecomment-175736761.

Comment: Hi Marco, seeing how the protocol required is clearly SOAP shouldn't the GCM plug-in URL start with WSS:// ?

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) have released a browser agnostic library that allows you to accept push messages from arguably the current leader in Push Message providers, regardless of your choice of Chrome, FireFox, Opera, and soon Edge.

Great news!