# Change service worker subscribe endpoint

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

So I'm trying to get into the Push API and I set up a very basic example with an empty service-worker.js and an index.js that just triggers the subscription for now:

```
function subscribeUserToPush() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.register('service worker.js').then(function(registration) {
        var subscribeOptions = {
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(
            'foobarkeyoffoobarness'
            )
        };

        return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
    }).then(function(pushSubscription) {
        console.log('PushSubscription: ', pushSubscription);
        return pushSubscription;
    });
}
```

and the subscription endpoint I get send back is something like "fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dfyodk6jd3c:APA91bETwSnoOpagCulOlD11XJu7savlJXp4hwEqKeqldHJxW6_WQTfjNTKjsT9JpY1auK...."

**Now my question is**: is it actually possible (even if it is a bad idea) to have a custom push-service endpoint, a self hosted solution?

Does Google firebase actually have the monopoly on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [offered link](http://%20https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/how-push-works) states, **Each browser can use any push service they want, it's something developers have no control over**

I needed to use Push Notification in an organization which uses local network and it has no access to internet, but turns out service worker push notification doesn't fit for intranet at least for now, maybe in  near future there will be some solutions, there is an alternative named SignalR technology, but as you might know it doesn't work when browser tab is closed and therefore SignalR on the contrary to WbPush can't wake up closed web browser.

Maybe the only hope is **dom.push.serverURL** which you can read more about it in [here](https://medium.com/@jconlin_89117/roll-your-own-push-server-kind-of-7d36c997a768).
I also learned that Firefox uses [Autopush](https://mozilla-push-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as Push Service.
Here are some links which says you can't:
[WebPush without third party](https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush/issues/32) - 
[Change Push provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36771863/4344976)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I never thought of the problem with offline/intranet applications! If one does not need the advantage of the browser calling the serviceworker in the background aka if the page is desktop only and is open anyway, one could implement an own solution using node for example

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is interested: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/how-push-works

> During the subscription flow the browser requests a subscription from
>   the messaging server. Each browser vendor has it’s own messaging
>   server, but your browser knows which server to call.